UDF In Snowflake SQL
Not sure why doesn't this work:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_FiscalYear(AsOf DATETIME) RETURNS INT AS

$$ 
    DECLARE Answer INT; 
BEGIN 
    CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(AsOf) < 7 THEN 
        Answer := YEAR(AsOf)
    ELSE 
        Answer := YEAR(AsOf) + 1 
    END; 
    Return Answer; 
END; 
$$;

Not sure why this isn't compiling.  I keep getting: syntax error line 2 at position 12 unexpected 'Answer'. (line 2)
I have years of experience in TSQL but snowflake gives me fits.  Thanks in advance.

I don't use Snowflake, but the issue you observe is not caused by the RDBMS. You can't use CASE like this, you rather need IF. See on this sample fiddle how to fix your function in MSSQL. According to the documentation, the same syntax should work in Snowflake, too.

The example of a SQL UDF takes the form:
CREATE FUNCTION area_of_circle(radius FLOAT)
  RETURNS FLOAT
  AS
  $$
    pi() * radius * radius
  $$
  ;

Thus your SQL following this form would be:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_FiscalYear(AsOf DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT 
AS
$$ 
    YEAR(AsOf) + iff(MONTH(AsOf) < 7, 0, 1) 
$$;

and that is happy,
select  fnc_FiscalYear('2024-9-25'::date);


if you really want CASE then:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_FiscalYear(AsOf DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT 
AS
$$ 
    YEAR(AsOf) + case when MONTH(AsOf) < 7 then 0 else 1 end 
$$;


Just to add to what Simeon shared, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-introduction#general-usage states that a SQL UDF evaluates an arbitrary SQL expression and returns the result(s) of the expression. It cannot include multiple statements.
